# Sencha Touch and Clusterize.js, passing down touch scroll events

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, scroll, touch

I am trying to get a very large list to scroll cleanly and would like to implement Clusterize.js but Sencha seems to grab the touch scroll events and won't let them pass down.

Clusterize.js URL: http://nexts.github.io/Clusterize.js/

I started a fiddle which shows the plain list and its performance, I am working on implementing Clusterize...: http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyV/9hds0has/

Note: I need this to work and perform well on IE for weaker mobile tablets.

I don't want to enable the scroller on the HTML panel because that will just interfere.

I did try to enable the scroller and then add listeners to push the events down and disable propagation but that did not work.

```
{
    direction:'vertical',
    scroller: {
        listeners:{
            scrollstart:function(a,b,c){
                // stop the scroller an pass on the event;
                return false;

            },
            scroll:function(a,b,c){
                // stop the scroller an pass on the event;
                console.log('[scrollable][on scroll]');
                return false;

            },
            scrollend:function( scroller, x, y, eOpts ){
                // stop the scroller an pass on the event;
                console.log('[scrollable][on scrollend]x='+x+', y='+y);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also looked at relayEvent and relayEvents but those seem to be geared to push events between ext widgets..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is DONT!

Clusterize.js is a very cool way to implement Infinite scrolling but that functionality is already built into the Sencha List widget.  The only problem is that for it to work or work properly you need to upgrade to Sencha Touch 2.4.2

For more information on how to get it going see the following StackOverFlow question:
[Sencha Touch - How to enable Infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036321/sencha-touch-how-to-enable-infinite-scroll)