# Overlaying in list items with Sencha Touch app

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I am developing a Sencha Touch app with lists, specifically in one list we have (for example) 400 different items and it is necessary to include the parameter `infinite: true` to improve the performance in the view..

But I am looking a strange behavior and the items are overlaying  with the next one..

[image]

My code is:

```
xtype        : 'list',
cls          : 'mweb-list',
useComponents: true,
maxItemCache: 30,
useHeaders   : false,
infinite   : true,
```

This behavior is happening when I include the `infinite` parameter..

Component cls has not css rules, here you can view the extended component:

```
Ext.define('xx.components.list.BaseListComponent', {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
  xtype : 'mwebBaseListComponent',

  config: {
    cls          : 'mweb-list',
    useComponents: true,
    emptyText    : '',
    loadingText  : '',
    useHeaders   : false
  }
});
```

Any clue??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the flag variableHeights:true.

```
xtype        : 'list',
cls          : 'mweb-list',
useComponents: true,
maxItemCache: 30,
useHeaders   : false,
infinite   : true,
variableHeights: true,
```

Other than that your mweb-list might be setup for normal lists, but not following the structure of infinite lists.
If variableHeights does not help please post your css code.

css:

```
.mweb-list {
    --> post whatever is in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `infinite: true`, you can use the `itemHeight` property to set the height (in pixels) of each list item.

```
xtype        : 'list',
cls          : 'mweb-list',
useComponents: true,
maxItemCache: 30,
useHeaders   : false,
infinite   : true,
itemHeight : 80
```

Comment: Sorry but with itemHeight is not working.. It is the same behavior .. Thank you for your response..

Comment: Does it look ok if you use `infinite: false`?

Comment: Really I am using the code specified with infinite:true.. I am very confused about this..

Comment: I asked if the items look ok when you remove the `infinite: true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107928/discussion-between-inane-and-bumpy).